# I want to track live game data for League of Legends, but I dont know to get that data

Tags: python

my problem is that I want to track live game data for league of legends, such as enemy champion armor, your lethality/armor penetration etc. Does anyone know how I can get this (and I know this is possible since many applications for league of legends out there have live game data trackers)

Comment: Did you take a look at the Riot API: https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Riot API, they should have the data there.

The link:  developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol

Comment: Note the guidance about "off-site resource requests" in the "Some Questions Are Still Off-Topic" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and the corresponding (final) bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer